# why does the Selenium IDE script doesnt work for next use

Tags: selenium, ide, selenium-ide

Am new to selenium, so please clear my doubt if possible. Why does the selenium IDE testscript doesnot work after few days, what is the alternative method to choose standard path, so that i can use the script for next use

Comment: Do you seriously expect any kind of useful answer? Please have a read through [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium IDE is a tool that allow to record user's action - if your pages contains dynamic elements, ajax, waiting etc. your Selenium IDE tests will often end by fail, because of page will be another every new loading

Another case - developers did changes on the page therefore you should update (rerecord) your failed tests or locate the error manually (play failed tests step by step, find error and apply better locators)

Use Selenium IDE for simple sites with simple code that will not be changed in future. For complex pages Selenium IDE is not a good solution.